# How can I specify optional query filters in Prisma?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, prisma

I am building an application with React, Apollo and Prsima that allows users to filter cars by model, brand, price... I know (for example) how to filter cars by brand:

```
const GET_CARS = gql`
  query FilterCars($brandId: ID){
    cars(where: {   
        model : { brand: { id: $brandId } }
    }) {
        id
        model {
            name
            brand {
             name
            }
            horses
        }
        year
        km
        price
        ...
  }
`;
```

And in the component:

```
const CarList = (props) => {
    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_CARS, {
        variables: {
            brandId: "exampleBrandId"
        }
    })

    ...
}
```

The problem is, that some parameters are optional: maybe the user does not care about the brand, or the model, or the price... So then all cars should appear: If no brand is selected, cars of all brands should appear; If no price is selected, cars of all prices should appear...

How can I do that? Something like:

```
query FilterCars($brandId: ID){
    cars(where: {   
        model : { brand: { id: $brandId || all_brand_ids } }
    }) {
    ...
    }
}
```

I have investigated a and found a possible [solution](https://www.prisma.io/forum/t/optional-query-filters/355), but the custom input that the post refers to is not generated in my prisma.

Comment: Have you tried setting a default query that displays all. So when you first enter the page, is there a default selection selected, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Yes, @Leafyshark there is a `select` that has the default value `all` selected.

Comment: Oh I see, so can you not write some middleware that queries all cars and returns them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
getCars(parent, args, {prisma}, info){
  const queryArgs ={}
  if(args.brandId){
     queryArgs ={
       where: {
         model: {
          id: args.brandId
       }
      }
    }
  }

 if(args.price){
    queryArgs={
      ...queryArgs,
      where: {
      ...queryArgs.where
      //What every you want to add
      }
    }
 }

  return prisma.query.cars(queryArgs, info)
}
```

You can check on the Backend your args. And create a flexible obj to query for...

Answer (score 11):

The [answer from @Toiz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60912351/9311354) is feasible. However, what if the number of parameters increases so that multiple if-statements are needed?

I suggest using `undefined`.

As mentioned in prisma official docs [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/null-and-undefined), you can use `undefined` to optioanally exclude a field from query.

For example,

```
where: {   
  model : { 
    brand: { 
      id: $brandId != null ? $brandId : undefined
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const GET_CARS = gql`
  query FilterCars($brandId: ID){
    cars(where: {   
        model : { brand: { id: $brandId } }
    }) {
        id
        model {
            name
            brand {
             name
            }
            horses
        }
        year
        km
        price
  }
`;

const CarList = (props) => {
    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_CARS, {
        variables: {
            brandId: "exampleBrandId"
        }
    })
}
```

brandId: "exampleBrandId" - this should be dynamic, and one of the options could be something like "All Brands", which would then query all brands.

Comment: I do not think this solution works. Prisma will query all cars that have a model with an id of "exampleBrandId", which will be 0 because no car has an id of "exampleBrandId"

Comment: @Xalsar the solution is to make "exampleBrandId" a variable, and thus dynamic. Then you could have a select list of options such as: "Lamborghini" "Ferrari" "Porsche" and finally, "All" which would return all... Would that work? I am thinking about it in the context of Prisma / Next / Apollo to be fair!